# javascript jquery show/hide of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<table id='mytab'>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">OS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Fedora</td>
        <td>Cent Os</td>
        <td>Ubuntu</td>
        <td>Suse</td>
        <td>Redhat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">Versions</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>v2.4</td>
        <td>beta 2</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>2008</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>v3.4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>2009</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>v4.4</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>2010</td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">Support</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>All Support Free</td>
        <td>Partial Support</td>
        <td>Paid Support</td>
        <td>Community Support</td>
        <td>Full support</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jquery

```
      $('#mytab td').hide();
      $('#mytab td:nth-child(1)').show();
     $('#mytab td:nth-child('whatever_column_selected')').show();
```

whenever whatever_column_selected, it's suppose to show the selected column, it's displaying and also displaying OS,version and support

so what I want is if suse is seleced then it's suppose to display in the following format:
OS - > Suse

Versions - > 8 9 10

Support - > Community Support

If I need to replace the tables to div to get the output desired results, that'll also work

Thanks in advance

Comment: Selected how? Are there links on that first row? Behavior attached directly to the `td`s?

Comment: I'm confused how can you select `Suse`? to the fact that it is hidden... hmmm...

Comment: there is a javascript function so whenever somebody clicks on the fedora or suse or whatever that cell will get attached. Links are onto the second line

Comment: once you click on the suse, it'll hide other (fedora,cent,ubuntu and redhat).

Comment: @dave, so initially or are visible?

Comment: yes, all is visible when the page is loaded.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455699/show-hide-table-column-with-colspan-using-jquery for answer with colspan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the html [here](http://jsfiddle.net/X2DBv/) with few changes..

```
$(function(){  
    $('#mytab tr.header td').click(function(){
        var index = $(this).index() + 1;
        $('#mytab tr td:nth-child(' + index + ')').siblings().hide();
    })
});​
```

---

**update** [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X2DBv/1/)

```
$(function(){

    $('th').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).data('text',text);
    });
    $('#mytab tr.header td').click(function(){
        var index = $(this).index() + 1;
        $('#mytab tr:has(th)').each(function(){
            var str = $(this).nextUntil('tr:has(th)')
                .find(':nth-child('+index+')').map(function(){
                return $(this).text();
            }).get().join(" ");
            $(this).find('th').html(function(){
                return $(this).data('text') + '<span>--&gt; ' + str + '</span>';
            })
        });
    })
});​
```

Comment: Thanks Reigel for the answer but there is no problem in show/hide.

There is the problem in display of Data.

If something is clicked/selected then the format of display is suppose to be like this

<table>
<tr>
<td> OS</td><td>  Suse  </td>   
</tr>  
<tr>  

<td>Versions </td>  
<td>8</td>  
<td> 9</td>  
<td> 10  </td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td>Support </td>  
<td>  Community Support   </td>  
</tr>  
<table>

Thanks

Comment: oh?.. you want it to display as like a string? like put `OS - > Suse Versions - > 8 9 10 Support - > Community Support` below the table?

Comment: I m sorry if my words are confusing,

suse's versions are listed in three different rows, 8 9 10,

so whenever version is displayed, it's supposed to be on the left side, and 8 9 10 on the right hand side. (Version is currently displayed first then on the next row 8 and next row 9 and last one is 10) so all is suppose to be in one line.

Comment: So a click on a column should generate a new table, two columns, "summarizing" the original column's data?

Comment: Suppose there are images in one column then how can that be done ?  

Thanks in advance

Comment: just replace `return $(this).text();` with `return $(this).html();` inside the `.map(function(){...})`...

Comment: Hello Reigel,

instead of using   $('#mytab tr.header td').click(function(){

I m calling my own onclick function

it's working fine, but everytime it's called, TH's Data is not getting replaced. Means if OS is having Suse, after clicking of other or same column it's adding data after suse instead of replacing it with the suse.

and it's happening in every row.

Please help

Thanks
Dave

Comment: Hello Reigel,

can you tell me how to remove the data of TH on some button's click, and I'll try to solve that problem of repeating.


Thanks in adcance

Comment: Well, you could post your problem here at SO, that would be nice.. :)

Comment: Thanks Reigel,

There was a glitch in my code, And now my problem is solved :)

Thanks for the support